# How to encode front slash in android? (%2F not working)

Tags: android

Kindly help me to solve the following issue in android...

How to send a string containing forwardslash ("/"), in Url to get JSON data in Android?

Example: 
Suppose if following is the URL,
https://www.example.com/xyz/abc/phone/ios/android
I want to append Url with "ios/android" for "phone" (as String, not as a Query Parameter), but it is taking as, two values "ios" and "android". And returning...
{"exception":"Missing value for parameter android"}﻿

1) Tried with "URLEncoder" , but it is not taking.
2) Tried replacing front slash("/") with "%2F ", "%252F" etc.. but it is returning blank array ("[ ]").﻿

Comment: Try with %21 it may be work for you

Comment: You should try using the `Uri.Builder` class. Fairly sure it handles encoding

Comment: 1) Encoding with %21 not working, returning blank array again

2) For android.net.Uri.Builder; I tried like this:
   
      Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
   builder.scheme("https")
        .authority("www.example.com")
        .appendPath("xyz")       
        .appendPath("abc")
        .appendPath("phone")
        .appendPath("ios/android");
   String myUrl = builder.build().toString();

But I am getting response: "Not Found"
When I tried to display the Url: it encoded it as "ios%2Fandroid"

Answer (score 0):

The correct encoding is:

```
 https://www.example.com/xyz/abc/phone/ios%2fandroid
```

If this is not understood by the server, the server is broken. See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for reference.